# Creating nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an existing JSON model like

```
    var oData = {
{section: "section1",description: "item1 description",checked: true }
{section: "section1",description: "item2 description",checked: true }
{section: "section2",description: "item1 description",checked: true }
{section: "section2",description: "item2 description",checked: true }
{section: "section3",description: "item1 description",checked: true }
}
```

I am attempting to create a structure like this from the existing json model

```
  var oData = {
    {section: "section1" 
             {description: "item1 description",checked: true } ,
             {description: "item2 description",checked: true }
    }
    {section: "section2" 
             {description: "item1 description",checked: true } ,
             {description: "item2 description",checked: true }
    }
    {section: "section3" 
             {description: "item1 description",checked: true } }
    }
```

I am looking for the best way to accomplish this

Comment: Neither of those code snippets are JSON. They aren't even valid JavaScript.

Comment: The desired result you provided is incorrect. You are mixing types up "section1" {desc... - it's all bad. So your request is invalid.

Comment: Those are javascript object literals (malformed ones at that) not JSON.

Comment: the structure listed by daksh works how can the existing model be restructured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deciding the best way is tough without knowing about the way you wanna use it but this might help:

```
var oData = {
    sections : [{name: "section1",
                items : {
                        item1 : {description : "description goes here", checked : true},
                        item2 : {description : "description goes here", checked : true} 
                        }
                },
                {name: "section2", 
                 items : {
                        item1 : {description : "description goes here", checked : true},
                        item2 : {description : "description goes here", checked : true} 
                        }
                 }
                ]}
```

Comment: this would work , how can I modify the existing model to use this structure?

Comment: I think i have written a modified structure. Are you talking about the model in your backbone code?

Comment: yes, sorry what I mean is how can I loop through the original structure to create the model you have provided.

Comment: ok, the problem in looping is that your oData is not a valid json or even a javascript object literal. There is no key or index to loop over and hence it cant be achieved. Something can still be done if you can tell me how can you create it in the first place. :)